# insert data in sql server from other table

Tags: sql-server, database

I've some records in table_3 and I want to insert that record to table_2 but value of first column (Id) will be (NUMBER+1) of table_1. My code is

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(Id,NAME)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM TABLE_1)+1 AS Id,name
FROM TABLE_3
```

Count of table_1 is 200. and count of TABLE_3 is 10. I want new inserted Ids are like

**(201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210)**

but from query am getting is like...

**(201,201,201,201,201,201,201,201,201,201)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it simply with `only one select` using `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `group by`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(Id,NAME)
 SELECT MAX(NUMBER) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name),name
 FROM TABLE_3
 group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query `(SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM TABLE_1)+1` is always the same, since `MAX(NUMBER)` is just `200`.

If you want to increment by 1 for each new record inserted, *starting at* `(SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM TABLE_1)+1`, try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (Id, NAME)
SELECT Id + rn, name 
FROM (
   SELECT (SELECT MAX(NUMBER) FROM TABLE_1) AS Id, name,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
   FROM TABLE_3 ) t
```

Comment: ooopss..isn't there any other way to do this? I've around 30 columns. I've to write them again and again.

Comment: @NailaAkbar Can you please edit the OP by adding one more column in table schema as well as sample data?

Comment: What do you mean by OP?

Comment: @NailaAkbar Original Post, that is your question.